# Convert: no decode delegate errors in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

After updating my R installation on my Mac with a couple of packages (most recently, RODBC), when I knit .Rmd files to pdf, I get error such as the one below.

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `images.trial/pressure-1.png'.
convert: missing an image filename
```

It occurs on .Rmd files that I've written on a Windows machine, and on a standard .Rmd file that I created from the base template (File>New File>R markdown...), with an initial r chunk that I've used to set knitr chunk options:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,fig.path="images/",dev="png")
```
````

If I exclude that `knitr::opts_chunk` code when I knit to pdf, I get no errors; if I knit to html with that `knitr:opts_chunk` intact, I get no errors.

I've run this on .Rmd files that have worked without errors in the past and on .Rmd files that were created directly from the template.